# php floats, objects and precision

Tags: php, object, precision

Playing with some calculations and noticed something odd. Here's a dump of some calculated numbers stored in an object.

```
  ["julianTime"]=>
  float(0.92518518518519)
  ["julian"]=>
  float(2459516.4251852)
  ["j2000"]=>
  float(2021.8245727178)
  ["b1950"]=>
  float(2021.8247835323)
  ["j1900"]=>
  float(2021.8245727178)
  ["delta"]=>
  float(72.316207312938)
  ["terrestrial"]=>
  float(2459516.4251852)
  ["universal"]=>
  float(2459516.4243482)
```

It appears to be chopping off the decimal to fit a specific length.  Calculating the same numbers on the same machine using JS, I get this:

```
"julianTime": 0.9251851851851852,
"julian": 2459516.4251851854,
"j2000": 2021.8245727178246,
"b1950": 2021.8247835323352,
"j1900": 2021.8245727178246,
"delta": 72.3162073129384,
"terrestrial": 2459516.4251851854,
"universal": 2459516.4243481923,
```

Now I know I've seen php and js do some really really strange things with precision and JSON.  And Ive ini_set("precision", 14) and php is still chopping off the decimal places.

Is this because it's being stored in an object???

Comment: How did you generate them? What makes you think that JS does the exact same calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important phrases in your question:

> Here's a dump of ...

What you are seeing is *a string representation* of numbers which are actually stored in a complicated binary format called "floating point".

The numbers shown are **not** what PHP is using internally to calculate further values.

> I've used ini_set("precision", 14)

If you count the "significant digits" (after any leading zero) in the examples shown, you will see that they all have exactly 14, as you requested.

The [manual page for that setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) says:

> The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers. -1 means that an enhanced algorithm for rounding such numbers will be used.

So if you try `ini_set("precision", -1)`, you may see a different result. **It won't change the actual values calculated, though, just the display.**

The **actual precision** used in calculations is not configurable, it is part of PHP, and is not easy to understand without first understanding what "floating point" means. See the reference question titled "[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/157957)".

Comment: I assumed that ini setting reflected the decimal precision of the number, not the whole number's precision.  Apparently that means that if I have  the precision at 14 and a number with 12 integer digits, I only get2 decimal points.  That just makes no sense to me.

Comment: @uPrompt "Significant digits" is a fairly common concept, and not unique to PHP. In relative terms, 0.00000000000002 is twice 0.00000000000001, but 123456789012.002 is only a tiny fraction of a percent higher than 123456789012.001. The concept of floating point numbers uses a similar trade-off - the range of magnitudes which can be represented is greater, at the cost of precision. If you need high precision maths, you need to use a library such as GMP or BCMath.